# Using babel-standalone in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, polyfills

I am using `babel-standalone` and I am doing the exact same thing as https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone/blob/master/examples/scriptTag-src.htm, but I get the warning

> You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/

I don't know what to do. Shouldn't it just translate all my ES6 code to code supported by older browsers?

Answer (score 18):

It's just a warning, nothing to worry about.

It's just telling you that you shouldn't run Babel in the browser *on production sites*, because running Babel in the browser is slower than precompiling your files with Babel, because the browser will have to compile your files every time you open a page. But if you're running it for development or personal pages, or if you just don't care (e.g., you don't have that much code), you won't need to worry about this warning.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks! What happened to be a problem was that all my code was inside `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {` and it was never evaluated, but didn't fire any errors. I removed this, and now it works.. It actually seems that no event listeners work any longer, but it doesn't fire any errors

Comment: How much slower, though, exactly? 2x, 10x 100x slower?

Comment: How does someone switch to the precompiled version?